# If $x^*Kx\ge0$ $\mathop \Rightarrow \limits^? $ $\overline {{x^*}Kx} = {x^*}{K^*}x$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $K\in M_n$ be invertible, and $x\in \mathbb{C}^n $ and $x^*Kx\ge0$.

Can we say that $\overline {{x^*}Kx}  = {x^*}{K^*}x$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since ${x^*}Kx = {({x^*}{K^*}x)^*} = \overline {{x^*}{K^*}x} $

then ${x^*}{K^*}x = \overline {{x^*}Kx} $.

Comment: Instead of editing the question, you can just mention in your answer that the hypothesis that $K$ is invertible is unnecessary.